# <column definition name> or <table constraint> expected, got 'Index'

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have got the error message " or  expected, got 'Index'" when I was trying to create a table and I do not really understand why is the code expecting a column definition or table constraint at this line

I have tried with changing the whitespaces, however that only change the place where the error is prompted. The content of the error message does not change

This is the part that I have declared the strings

```
 public class TaskEntry implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String TABLE = "Users";
        public static final String INDEX = "Index";
        public static final String COL_TASK_TITLE = "title";
    }
```

The following is my code for the creating table part

```
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + Item_contract.TaskEntry.TABLE + " ( " +
                Item_contract.TaskEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,  " +
                Item_contract.TaskEntry.INDEX + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                Item_contract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL" + ");";

        db.execSQL(createTable);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use INDEX as a column name as it is a keyword.

> The SQL standard specifies a large number of keywords which may not be
> used as the names of tables, indices, columns, databases, user-defined
> functions, collations, virtual table modules, or any other named
> object. The list of keywords is so long that few people can remember
> them all. For most SQL code, your safest bet is to never use any
> English language word as the name of a user-defined object.

[SQL As Understood By SQLite - SQLite Keywords](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)

So change

```
 public static final String INDEX = "Index";
```

perhaps to

```
public static final String INDEX = "IX";
```

You could enclose the column name if you really wanted it to be INDEX e.g.

```
public static final String INDEX = "[Index]";
```

As per :-

```
If you want to use a keyword as a name, you need to quote it. There are four ways of quoting keywords in SQLite:

'keyword'       A keyword in single quotes is a string literal.
"keyword"       A keyword in double-quotes is an identifier.
[keyword]       A keyword enclosed in square brackets is an identifier. This is not standard SQL. This quoting mechanism is used by MS Access and SQL Server and is included in SQLite for compatibility.
`keyword`       A keyword enclosed in grave accents (ASCII code 96) is an identifier. This is not standard SQL. This quoting mechanism is used by MySQL and is included in SQLite for compatibility.
```

[SQL As Understood By SQLite - SQLite Keywords](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)

## Note

You will have to do one of the following to get the onCreate method to run and thus alter the schema:-

- Delete the App's data.
- Uninstall the App.